# How to Dynamically Swap-Out View Controllers Within TabBarViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uitabbarcontroller

So this is pretty advanced and I am not sure if it is feasible in the iOS SDK but here goes (please read carefully, I don't want skimmers preemptively answering this question before they know the details):

I have a tab bar view controller with two tabs. One tab (view controller 1) holds a data-presenting view controller, and the other (view controller 2) is a settings view. In the settings view I allow the user to specify whether they want to view a simplified or advanced version of the interface of view controller 1.

What I need to do, is based on these settings, present the chosen view for view controller 1, and I want to be able to do it on the fly (the user doesn't have to close and then reopen the app). I attempted to recreate the view controller array of the tab bar within

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController 
shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

but it just caused my app to crash (SIGABRT crash), go figure...

I was thinking of making a "hollow" view controller that would be able to point to the appropriate class type but the challange I have there is making it completely transparent to any view I should choose to place in it (`UITableViewController`, `UIViewController`, etc.).

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried looking at the docs at all [UITabBarController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?

```
- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Comment: I did, but I was focused mostly on the tab bar delegate methods to be honest. Additionally, in the shouldSelectViewController: method I was attempting to use this method which didn't turn out to be such a good idea. I ended up calling this method from the settings view when the user specifies which view he/she would like to use and it worked like a charm! :)